# Create/change a date stamp every time a cell is modified

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, triggers

I am trying to figure out how to create a date stamps, that get modification anytime a change is done in a cell. I am also very new to Google App Script (everybody needs to start somewhere).

I found the following code on how to create the date stamp :

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Test" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 8 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

which work for adding the date stamp in the column G, for any data filled in column H.

But if I wanna change the data in H2 for any value, the date in G2 stay the same.

Anybody could make suggestions please.

Comment: Welcome. Maybe you should start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: I don't understand this `But if I wanna change the data in H2 for any value, the date in G2 stay the same.`  Can you provide some images show examples of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your code includes the condition `if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )`

This means that a time stamp will only be set if `nextCell` (the cell in column G) is empty

If you want the timestamp to updated **every time** a value in column H is changed  -remove this condition.

So:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Test" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 8 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @ziganotschka, I tried the code, but I get the following error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (ligne 7, fichier "test")"

Comment: Hello, after some additional testing, it works. Thank you for your help